# White pixelated domain when viewed in viewport shading

Tags: 3d-view

I'm new to blender and am trying to simulate a smoke effect. However, when I try to view the smoke through "Viewport Shading" everything within my domain becomes white and pixelated. Does anyone know the cause and possible solution to this?

Here is a video of issue in motion: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J2b1xQaF137debneBBMO8TbIHxHDp5rx/view

[image: Screenshot of my workspace]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to reduce your emission strength[image]